# changes in web console have no effect

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

trying to follow this guide.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

changes made to network interfaces in the web console have no effect in the underlying files.  Selecting DHCP and DNS and specifying the range doesn't build a scope in /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

setting up eth0, 1, 2 make no changes to the underlying /etc/network/interfaces file.

The guide stops working for me at step 3:

Fill in the other details, like gateway and DNS, in the networks that were auto-created for each NIC.

Unfortunately it didn't autocreate any interfaces for my NICs.

Answer (score 0):

MAAS uses a different configuration file for dhcpd, so you won't see changes in `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`. Checkout the process listing:

```
 1048 ?        Ss     0:08 /usr/sbin/dhcpd -user dhcpd -group dhcpd -f -q -4 -pf /run/maas/dhcp/dhcpd.pid -cf /etc/maas/dhcpd.conf -lf /var/lib/maas/dhcp/dhcpd.leases br0
```

The file MAAS controls is `/etc/maas/dhcpd.conf` and that's where it will write DHCP changes to.

Regarding `/etc/network/interfaces`, MAAS does not manage this file. MAAS will read it and "import" the interface names and some other info, but that's it. If you tell it to fully manage a certain NIC (DHCP + DNS), the information you provide there will be given to clients booting from there, and not to write back to `/etc/network/interfaces`.